# How to extend AspNetUserRoles table

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a .NET application that uses EntityFramework 6.2.0 for creating and managing my database. I also have a class that inherits from `IdentityDbContext`.

I understand that upon issuing an initial `update-database` command my database is created with an `AspNetUserRoles` table, containing two columns: `UserId` and `RoleId`.

My question is: how can I extend this table to included two additional columns: `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy`, where each column will hold a GUID value.

I'd like for these two columns to be updated via code as well, so something along the lines of adding them also as properties to the `IdentityUserRole` class.

I've tried to do this already by creating a custom `ApplicationUserRole` class and inheriting from `IdentityUserRole`, but whenever I try adding a new migration I see this `Discriminator` column pop up.

Is there a way for me to also do away with this new columm?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: how can I extend this table to included two additional
> columns: CreatedBy and UpdatedBy, where each column will hold a GUID
> value

Before jump directly into your question, few things need to explain.
Although it's easy to directly modify the existing `AspNetUserRoles` table to add your two additional fields, it's generally not recommended for several reasons.

If you directly modify `AspNetUserRoles` class or table you might encounter compatibility issues. Because, in future updates to the ASP.NET Identity framework might modify the table structure, causing conflicts with your custom changes. This can lead to breaking changes and difficulties with upgrades. This way this approach might not be the ideal implementation.

> I've tried to do this already by creating a custom ApplicationUserRole
> class and inheriting from IdentityUserRole, but whenever I try adding
> a new migration I see this Discriminator column pop up

You're right and getting the expected output. When directly inheriting from `IdentityUserRole` and adding new properties, the "Discriminator" column appears due to Entity Framework's [Table-per-Hierarchy (TPH) inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration) strategy. It maps different inheriting classes (like your ApplicationUserRole) to a single table.

> I'd like for these two columns to be updated via code as well, so
> something along the lines of adding them also as properties to the
> IdentityUserRole class. Is there a way for me to also do away with
> this new columm?

Rather modifying existing table, you can create a separate table to store the additional information about user-role relationships, including the CreatedBy and UpdatedBy columns. This table can have foreign keys referencing the `AspNetUsers` and `AspNetRoles` tables.

This approach offers more flexibility in terms of storing additional data, but it requires more manual configuration.

In order to implement that, you could create new class for instance: You can define a new class (e.g., ApplicationUserRoleExtended) with properties for UserId, RoleId, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy.

Let's have a look in practice, how we can achive that:

New Model:

```
public class ApplicationUserRoleExtended : IdentityUserRole
{
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext Configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
        .WithMany(r => r.Users)
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
        .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRoleExtended>()
        .HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRoleExtended>()
        .HasOne(ur => ur.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.UserRoleExtended)
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRoleExtended>()
        .HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
        .WithMany(r => r.UserRoleExtended)
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);
}
```

Call New Method While Adding Role :

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store) : base(store)
    {
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> AddToRoleAsync(string userId, string roleName)
    {
        var user = await FindByIdAsync(userId);
        var role = await FindRoleAsync(roleName);

        if (user == null || role == null)
        {
            return IdentityResult.Failed("User or role not found");
        }

        if (user.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role.Id))
        {
            return IdentityResult.Succeeded(); 
        }

        var userRole = new ApplicationUserRoleExtended
        {
            UserId = user.Id,
            RoleId = role.Id,
            CreatedBy = CurrentUserId, 
            CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,// You can consider if the date required.
        };

        user.Roles.Add(userRole);

        return await UpdateAsync(user);
    }

   
}
```

**Note:** After above modification, use the Entity Framework Migrations tool to create a migration and update your database with the new table and relationships. Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration). In addition, [check this document](https://johnatten.com/2014/02/13/asp-net-mvc-5-identity-extending-and-modifying-roles/), might be helpful for you.